# C++: casting non constant to constant

Tags: c++, variables, scope, constants

I want to convert a non constant variable to constant variable. I tried using const_cast but still the following program is giving error that ‘bitsize1’ cannot appear in a constant-expression. What am i doing wrong ?

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

int l = 3; // taken input from user
int bitsize2 = (l * 2);

int bitsize1 = const_cast<int&>(bitsize2);
string temp = "100101";
bitset<const_cast<int&>(bitsize2)> baz (temp);
cout << baz;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: template parameters must be known at compile time.

Comment: You are getting confused between a constant expression and a const object.  `const` is for making an object non-modifiable, `constexpr` is for making a value available at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

const_cast is used to cast const *away* not to make something const. If you want constant expression the easiest way in post-C++11 programming is to use constexpr:

```
constexpr int l = 3;
constexpr int bitsize2 = l * 2;
```

The input from user cannot be a compile time constant expression so you must figure out something else.

Comment: `const_cast` can be used to remove **or add** `const`. Adding `const` can be done implicitly in some cases, but there are also cases where a `const_cast` is needed. You're right, though, that it won't turn a runtime value into a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are expanded in compile time, this means that all template arguments should be known when compiling. Obviously user input is runtime data thus cannot be used as a template argument.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, you cannot deduce template parameters at runtime.
You should look into using boost's [dynamic bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).
It exists for the exact problem that you have run into.

> "The dynamic_bitset class is nearly identical to the std::bitset class.
>   The difference is that the size of the dynamic_bitset (the number of
>   bits) is specified at run-time during the construction of a
>   dynamic_bitset object, whereas the size of a std::bitset is specified
>   at compile-time through an integer template parameter."